# How is `hold count` value useful in Reentrant Lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

Reentrant Lock ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html ) has a feature to state the strength of locking by a particular Thread which is based on the value of 'hold count'. It is initilized when a Thread aquires the lock and each time when it re-aquires the lock the value is incremented. The value is decremented each time the thread invokes the unlock method on the lock.

Single thread at a time can be the owner of the Reentrant Lock hence simple boolen flag makes mcuh sense rather than an integers count. A thread already being the owner of the lock can only re-aquire it so count seams not of much. (any) use.

What is the usefulness of hold count ? What are the use cases of it ? One such use case can be to check of the current thread is holding the lock (hold count value > 0). But there are different APIs like `isHeldByCurrentThread()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation for that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getHoldCount()) explains it :

> The hold count information is typically only used for testing and debugging purposes.

So it's basically a method that can help you track down instances where your code fails to call `unlock()`. This is especially true for cases where you have reentrant usage of the lock.

Comment: Hmm that is right but then we do have methods like `isHeldByCurrentThread()`

Comment: In case of reentrant usage, it is useful to have the count, to find out at what level the count is no longer in sync with your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a method includes a locked block, you can call it from different place. This method should do different thing according to the lock count it holds. Then you can take use of `getHoldCount`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Example {

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    void method1() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (lock.getHoldCount() == 1) { 
                System.out.println("call method1 directly");
            } else if (lock.getHoldCount() == 2) {
                System.out.println("call method1 by invoking it inside method2");
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void method2() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            method1();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.method1(); // call method1 directly
        example.method2();  // call method1 by invoking it inside method2
    }
}
```